# NodeMailer is working locally but not after i upload it to a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have set upped a Nodemailer with Oauth2 client, it works fine if i run it locally and its sending mails perfectly but after i upload to server its not working giving me this error:

At first I was using app passwords, it was too working locally but not on a server so i switched to Oauth2 still it giving me this same error ?

```
 Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o199-20020a3741d0000000b0074cd5a2f604sm1215644qka.68 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1548:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1527:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:953:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:755:14)
    at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/home/bhim/apps/LinkCollect-/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:193:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o199-20020a3741d0000000b0074cd5a2f604sm1215644qka.68 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2'
}
```

this is the code i have written for it :

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { USER, PASS, BACKEND_BASE_URL,CLIENT_ID_NodeMailer,CLIENT_SECRET_NodeMailer,REFRESH_TOKEN } = require("../config");
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const OAuth2_client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID_NodeMailer,CLIENT_SECRET_NodeMailer);
OAuth2_client.setCredentials({refresh_token:REFRESH_TOKEN});

const accessToken  = OAuth2_client.getAccessToken();




let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service :"gmail",
  port:587,
  secure:true,
         auth : {
            type :"OAuth2",
            user : USER,
            clientId : CLIENT_ID_NodeMailer,
            clientSecret : CLIENT_SECRET_NodeMailer,
            refreshToken :REFRESH_TOKEN,
            accessToken :accessToken
         }
});

module.exports = {
  verifyEmail: async function verifyUserEmail(name, userEmail, token) {
    try {
      let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `LinkCollect ${USER}`,
        to: userEmail,
        subject: "Email Verification",
        text: "HELLO" + name,
        html: `<h2>HELLO ${name}<h2/>
                      <h3> Thanks for using our services, Please verify your email </h3>
                      <a href="${BACKEND_BASE_URL}/api/v1/user/verify-email?token=${token}"> Verify You </a>
                    `,
      },function(error,result){
        if(error){
         console.log("err",error);
        } else {
          console.log(result);
        }
        transporter.close();}
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error",error);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: My first guess: `CLIENT_ID_NodeMailer,CLIENT_SECRET_NodeMailer` contain wrong values. Have you checked them? The error message mentions username and password. You should also check `USER` and `PASS`.

Comment: yes its working locally

Comment: Have you checked it in the server? It's unclear where the values come from. I hope you don't hardcode these values in your codebase. Are these environment variables or values from an `.env` file?

Comment: The error I have posted is from the server, it is coming from the line ```console.log('err',error)```
Yes all these environment variables are from ```.env``` file

Comment: Do you have the correct `.env` file on the server? Have you checked the values on the server?

Comment: yes i have checked that by adding a console statement... its printing all variables correctly